# How to add where on custom type in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, hibernate-criteria

EmployeeRepository class

```
CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
query.select(employee)
.where(employee.get("address.city").in("pune","Mumbai","Delhi"));// getting error here
```

Employee class

```
 class Employee {
private Long empId;
@Type(employeeCustomType)
private Address address; //this is custom type 
// setter and getter
}
```

Address class

```
class Address{
private String city;
private Integer zipCode;
}
```

please just assume we have employeeCustomType class

any one have any idea on it.
I am just trying to add where clause on address object of city parameter.
using CriteriaBuilder.

**Any other suggestion to achieve this scenario in hibernate**

Comment: That's not possible. How should that be translated to SQL? Hibernate has no knowledge of the structure of `Address`, so it also can't translate a path `address.city`. What kind of SQL type are you trying to map?

Comment: Hey Christian Beikov,

I want to generate below query using criteria builder where address is a custom datatype in postgress db.

`select * from employe
where (address).city in ("pune", "mumbai", "Delhi")`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov

Comment: You can introduce a custom `SQLFunction` to render this, but Hibernate does not yet support struct types out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you store `Address` in varchar field in the form of `city:zipCode` (example: `Delhi:110001`) then the following solution may help.

```
CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
query.select(employee).where(
    criteriaBuilder.or(
        criteriaBuilder.like(employee.get("address").as(String.class), "Delhi:%"),
        criteriaBuilder.like(employee.get("address").as(String.class), "Mumbai:%")
    )
);
```

Note: the main idea here is that you should represent `address` field as plain string when building criteria.